# On foundations: Axiomatic Set Theory and Category Theory

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I would like to pose two (not so distinct) questions.

1. Are there any resources/references for Tarski-Grothendieck (TA) axiomatic set theory? I am asking because I constantly run into the Wikipedia article and nothing else.
2. I have read that both TA and Neuman-Barneys-Goedel (NBG) leave a "window" open for the category theory (CT). But what about those attempts from the camp of CT to provide an axiomatic system without the need for the set?

I would appreciate any sharp reference regarding TA, NBG, and CT.

Comment: What sort of resources are you looking for in (1)?

Comment: I am looking for fundamental stuff, like e.g., the TA system itself.

Comment: You can find the original paper from the Mizar system somewhere on the web. I think there should be a reference in the Wikipedia page.

Comment: You are asking two questions. You should make two separate posts.